# In chrome, when in <p> some <a> or <strong> behave like they are in an "inline kinda absolute" position (you need to see the picture)

Tags: css, webkit

In chrome (and safari of course), I have this really weird behaviour that I don't understand :

[image]

I know my question is imprecise and I know that express it correcly would probably give me the answer. So if someone want to edit the question... :)

First, when I saw this behaviour on the `<strong>`, I thought it could be caused by the font. Font-face is used and a special bold font is used for the `<strong>` markup and mabye if it doesn't load properly... But since it occurs also on the `<a>`, I'm looking for another track.

The page is here : http://sciences.blogs.liberation.fr/home/2012/10/dix-questions-sur-s%C3%A9ralini-et-les-ogm-poisons.html

The code is classic :

`<p>L<a href="http://www.anses.fr/" target="_self">'Anses</a> et le <a href="http://www.hautconseildesbiotechnologies.fr/" target="_self">Haut Conseil des Biotechnologies</a> rendront leurs rapports sur le sujets le 20 octobre. L'Assemblée nationale auditionneront ensuite ces deux instances. Parmi les réactions récentes, voici également un texte du <strong>syndicat Sud</strong> de l'INRA (
<span class="asset  asset-generic at-xid-6a00e5500b4a648833017c3273ed58970b"><a href="http://sciences.blogs.liberation.fr/files/inra-expression-ogm-octobre-2012.pdf">ici en pdf</a></span>) qui conteste l'attitude de sa direction et réclame entre autre la mise en cause des procédures d'évaluation des produits phytosanitaires.</p>`

The css is too long to paste everything here since I have absolutely no idea about what could cause this behaviour. You can inspect it on the production page.

Weirdest thing : doesn't bug each time I load the page ; it appears to be random. This is why I first though about a font-face loading problem.

Comment: Would be much easier to solve if you got a minimal example behaving like this in a tool like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I've loaded it over 15 times, loads properly for me each time in Chrome.

Comment: @David Waters : This is the matter here, I can't find a minimal example of what is wrong with my code.

There's basicaly nothing special; just text in a <p> with <a> ans <strong> in it. I konw this is in the css, but I can't figure out wich particular point among everything in the css does that.

Comment: @cale_b Yes, this is like one on ten times. But enough for me to take screenshots.

Comment: Utilize Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature.  Right-click on the element, choose "Inspect element".  In the right-hand pane, hover over a style you suspect.  When you do, a checkbox appears - UN-check the checkbox to remove the style.  As you do this, you can discover which style(s) may be causing the problem.

Comment: @cale_b : of course, this is the way I debug website ; but the bug appears on the page load and wathever I change in the pannel, it resolve the bug (even if I change the color of another thing in the page).

So this is a really webkit thing ; probably about font-face and font loading. (the bug don't appear if I set the font-family to Verdana for instance)

Comment: I would believe this to be a problem with your custom `@font-face` loading crashing from time to time. You could try removing one definition in _src_ at the time. For some reasons, I'd suspect a line like `url('../fonts/sciences_texte_ital.svg#Sciences²texteItalic') format('svg')` to be the cause of the problem. (And since it's also from time to time and I can't reproduce it, it might be combined to a network issue too (just guessing))

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot Kraz.

The matter was that the svg version of the font was called before the ttf version. So Chrome was using the svg, causing the troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was about svg font.

The answer is : don't ever use svg fonts in chrome !